# How to read the response from Actions set in the Intents in LUIS

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I'm doing POC to understand LUIS for my project work.

I created an application in LUIS portal and added Intents and Entities. Also, set up some utterances for the intents. And for one of my Intent "Service", I configured Action "Utility- Write line".

When I use query which suits for the Intent "Service", it is returning json  where "Service" was a topscoringintent and also action along with parameter associated with this intent.

But how can I read the response of the action "Utility- Write line" associated with the intent "Service". I don't see any response data related to this action. Similarly, I could see other actions like GetWeather. Can you please explain, how can I get the responses of these actions?

I'm using C#

Thank you.

Nithya

Comment: Are u using C# or node?

Comment: Hi, I'm using c#.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to bind the action to either Microsoft Bot Framework or Slack bot.

Then the action would get triggered.

So, check if the action is bound or not to the bot framework.

You could also republish and check.

Please check [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=39L0Gv2EcSk) which shows a demo for LUIS.

Comment: Thank you. We are using the Microsoft bot framework to call the LUIS web service. But I don't find any article on how to get/retrieve the action associated with the intent in the Microsoft Bot Framework. Can you please guide if you know. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure you are using the latest BotBuilder NuGet package. Current version is [v3.5](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/releases/tag/Nuget3.5).

To check for the action, you need to navigate through the actual intent. The [IntentRecommendation](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/Luis/Models/IntentRecommendation.cs) has an [Actions](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/Luis/Models/IntentRecommendation.cs#L55) collection property.

The image below shows the full tree, including Action Parameters.

[image: Action parameters]

I don't think you will be able to get the Action response; though you might know if it [was triggered or not](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/Luis/Models/Action.cs#L39).

Comment: Is there any way to get the Action response?